# java - Overriding with covariant types wrt variables

Tags: java, overriding, ocpjp, covariant

```
class G {

    int x = 5;
}

class H extends G {

    int x = 6;
}

public class CovariantTest {

    public G getObject() {
        System.out.println("g");
        return new G();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CovariantTest c1 = new SubCovariantTest();
        System.out.println(c1.getObject().x);
        System.out.println(new H().x);
    }
}

class SubCovariantTest extends CovariantTest {

    public H getObject() {
        System.out.println("h");
        return new H();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
h
5
6
```

Apparently the two println statements in the main method aren't the same. How is the new H() object returned from class SubCovariant's getObject method assigned to a G reference?

Comment: **You will never get *5 as output* 
 with the code you posted !!**

Comment: Seems there is a typo error. Somewhere x should be 5 `int x = 5;`

Comment: thanks..edited to int x =5;

Answer (score 1):

G is the declared type, H is the actual type.

The declared type is what you can think of the object as, i.e. G in your example.

The actual type is what the object actually is, i.e. H in your example.  This provides actual behaviour, including any which it might inherit from parent classes including G.

Answer (score 1):

When you override a method, it is the type of the instance which matters, not the type of the reference.  This is how polymorphism works.

```
CovariantTest c1 = new SubCovariantTest();
```

This converts the type of the reference, but not the implementation. if you were to do

```
System.out.println(c1.getClass());
```

this would print

```
SubCovariantTest
```

so when you call `getObject()` on this instances, it should be no surprise that this calls `SubCovariantTest.getObject()`

---

By comparison, `static` methods don't follow polymorphism.  They cannot be overridden in the same way (they can only be hidden)  If you were to make `getObject()` static in both cases you would find that  `c1.getObject()` would call the matching the type of `c1` as the method to call is determined at compile time, not runtime.  In fact you can do this.

```
public class CovariantTest {

    public G static getObject() {
        System.out.println("g");
        return new G();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CovariantTest c1 = null;
        System.out.println(c1.getObject().x); // prints "g" "5"
    }
}

class SubCovariantTest extends CovariantTest {

    public H static getObject() {
        System.out.println("h");
        return new H();
    }
}
```

You can access a `null` reference here because it is not used at runtime.  The compiler only uses the type of the reference, as you might have expected in your question.